# Linux: 'Argument list too long' when I type anything

Tags: linux, bash

I'm working on Debian 8, and I've done something weird to my bash shell. No matter what I type, I see `Argument list too long`.

```
$ ls
-bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long
$ vi ~/.bashrc
-bash: /usr/bin/vi: Argument list too long
```

I also see this when I first log on - printing over and over again to the shell:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
-bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long
-bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
-bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long
....
```

I can't open my `.bashrc` file to work out what I've done, because I can't run any commands!

Help?

Comment: `/bin/bash --noprofile --norc` . Your PATH variable should only be `/usr/bin:/bin` but should be sufficient to fix your issue.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't finish the space on the `tmp` partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try switching shells ("ksh" for example) and then see if you can fix your bash environment.